# Microsoft.DirectX.DirectSound and TV Tuner

Tags: .net, directx, directshow, television, tv-tuner

Im currently using a WINTV Ministick from Hauppauge to stream to free TV channels. Whilst it works perfectly with the built in its native WinTv applciation, i cant seem to pick it up with the DirectSound API. The code im using to iterate through the devices is:

```
var cdc = new CaptureDevicesCollection();
    for (int i = 0; i < cdc.Count; i++)
    {
        lstDevices.Items.Add(cdc[i].Description.ToLower());
    }
    lstDevices.SelectedIndex = 1;
```

This only gives me my internal devices and the USB Web Camera i have as capture devices. Ive considered DirectShowNet but not sure if that will be able to pick up the USB stick either?

Anyone got any suggestions or sample code to do this?

Comment: Perhaps you can use GraphEdit to see what category the USB stick is registered under: maybe it is not registered as a capture source?

Comment: I've used graphedit to find the item. How would i link up the graph such that i could make the device part of the capture devices?

Comment: @Ralf its under the BDA source filters. Ive managed to put a graph together. Microsoft Netowrk Provider -> Hauppage SMS1000 DVB-T Tuner -> Hauppauge SMS1000 TS Capture -> MPEG2 Demux -> Microsoft DTV-DVD Audio Decoder. This graph plays but im not sure how this all links up to my original question?

Comment: That looks like you can't use the CaptureDevicesCollection to get hold of that device (though I'm not familiar with DirectSound at all): however you should be able to use DirectShow.net to accomplish the same. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd407292(v=vs.85).aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd375655(v=vs.85).aspx and http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd693007(v=vs.85).aspx